# Prove that a given recursively defined sequence converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Given:

Suppose that {$x_n$} is a bounded sequence such that
$$\begin{align*}
x_n&=x_{n-1}+\frac{f(n)}{10^n}\\\ 
\end{align*}$$
Where $f: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ and
$ x_1=1 $

How do I go about to formally prove that the sequence converges and show it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Hint:* The sequence is increasing.

Comment: ... and it is bounded

Comment: @Henry: I did not want to make it too easy :)

Answer (score 1):

The condition gives
$$x_n -x_{n-1}=\frac{f(n)}{10^n} \ge 0$$
which means the sequence is increasing. Also, $x_n$ is said to be bounded. Therefore, it converges.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: any increasing bounded sequence converges. Proof: the increasing bounded sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $\sup \{x_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ (easy to verify with $\delta-\epsilon$).

This is an increasing bounded sequence. Therefore, it converges.

Comment: @Henry Yes. It'd be pretty trivial to say any increasing bounded sequence is bounded.